# adding tenant user inside a property view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I'm trying to add a Tenant user inside a Property#show view. I have a form there like the following:

```
<%= form_for(@property.tenants) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="select">
  <%= f.select :type, [['Landlord'],['Tenant']] %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Add", %>  
<% end %>
```

The Tenant model is as follows:

```
class Tenant < User
  belongs_to :property
  def type
  "Tenant"
  end
end
```

and the Property model is as follows:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :bathrooms, :bedrooms, :postcode, :price
  belongs_to :branch
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :landlords, :through => :ownerships

  has_many :tenants
end
```

When I click on the Add button i'm magically redirected to the root path (/). 
I'm expecting it to add a new tenant for that specific property that I'm viewing in the show view but it just redirects me to the root path.

Feel free to ask for any clarifications
results of rake routes:

```
  tenants_index GET    /tenants/index(.:format)       tenants#index
   tenants_show GET    /tenants/show(.:format)        tenants#show
    tenants_new GET    /tenants/new(.:format)         tenants#new
  landlords_new GET    /landlords/new(.:format)       landlords#new
   tenants_edit GET    /tenants/edit(.:format)        tenants#edit
 tenants_create GET    /tenants/create(.:format)      tenants#create
 tenants_update GET    /tenants/update(.:format)      tenants#update
tenants_destroy GET    /tenants/destroy(.:format)     tenants#destroy
     properties GET    /properties(.:format)          properties#index
                POST   /properties(.:format)          properties#create
   new_property GET    /properties/new(.:format)      properties#new
  edit_property GET    /properties/:id/edit(.:format) properties#edit
       property GET    /properties/:id(.:format)      properties#show
                PUT    /properties/:id(.:format)      properties#update
                DELETE /properties/:id(.:format)      properties#destroy
          users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
      companies GET    /companies(.:format)           companies#index
                POST   /companies(.:format)           companies#create
    new_company GET    /companies/new(.:format)       companies#new
   edit_company GET    /companies/:id/edit(.:format)  companies#edit
        company GET    /companies/:id(.:format)       companies#show
                PUT    /companies/:id(.:format)       companies#update
                DELETE /companies/:id(.:format)       companies#destroy
       branches GET    /branches(.:format)            branches#index
                POST   /branches(.:format)            branches#create
     new_branch GET    /branches/new(.:format)        branches#new
    edit_branch GET    /branches/:id/edit(.:format)   branches#edit
         branch GET    /branches/:id(.:format)        branches#show
                PUT    /branches/:id(.:format)        branches#update
                DELETE /branches/:id(.:format)        branches#destroy
       sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)            sessions#create
    new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)        sessions#new
        session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)        sessions#destroy
         agents GET    /agents(.:format)              users#index
                POST   /agents(.:format)              users#create
      new_agent GET    /agents/new(.:format)          users#new
     edit_agent GET    /agents/:id/edit(.:format)     users#edit
          agent GET    /agents/:id(.:format)          users#show
                PUT    /agents/:id(.:format)          users#update
                DELETE /agents/:id(.:format)          users#destroy
      landlords GET    /landlords(.:format)           users#index
                POST   /landlords(.:format)           users#create
   new_landlord GET    /landlords/new(.:format)       users#new
  edit_landlord GET    /landlords/:id/edit(.:format)  users#edit
       landlord GET    /landlords/:id(.:format)       users#show
                PUT    /landlords/:id(.:format)       users#update
                DELETE /landlords/:id(.:format)       users#destroy
        tenants GET    /tenants(.:format)             users#index
                POST   /tenants(.:format)             users#create
     new_tenant GET    /tenants/new(.:format)         users#new
    edit_tenant GET    /tenants/:id/edit(.:format)    users#edit
         tenant GET    /tenants/:id(.:format)         users#show
                PUT    /tenants/:id(.:format)         users#update
                DELETE /tenants/:id(.:format)         users#destroy
           root        /                              static_pages#home
         signup        /signup(.:format)              users#new
         signin        /signin(.:format)              sessions#new
        signout DELETE /signout(.:format)             sessions#destroy
      dashboard        /dashboard(.:format)           static_pages#dashboard
           help        /help(.:format)                static_pages#help
          about        /about(.:format)               static_pages#about
        contact        /contact(.:format)             static_pages#contact
```

properties_controller.rb

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /properties
  # GET /properties.json
  def index
    @properties = Property.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @properties }
    end
  end
def show
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @property }
    end


  end

  # GET /properties/new
  # GET /properties/new.json
  def new
   # @property = Property.new
   @property = current_user.properties.build if signed_in?

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @property }
    end
    logger.debug("hello from new")
  end

  # GET /properties/1/edit
  def edit
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /properties
  # POST /properties.json
  def create
    #@property = Property.new(params[:property])
    @property = current_user.branch.properties.build(params[:property]) if signed_in?
    respond_to do |format|
      @property.user_id = current_user.id
      if @property.save
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: 'Property was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @property, status: :created, location: @property }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Show us your routes by doing `rake routes` in your terminal. Also show us your controller for Properties

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several things that doesn't seem quite right.

Try this.

Add @tenant instance variable to the show method of Properties controller.

```rb
def show
  ...
  @tenant = @property.tenants.build
end
```

And modify form_for line to this.

```rb
<%= form_for @tenant do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your  `properties_controller.rb`,

```
def show
 @tenant = Tenant.new
end
```

Your from should then be:

```
<%= form_for @tenant do |f| %>
```

You should also add a hidden field with the ID of the property for when you submit your form.

Then for your create action in `properties_controller.rb`

```
def create
   tenant = Tenant.new(params[:tenant])
   tenant.property_id = params[:property_id] #This is from that hidden field with your property_id and this also assumes you have a column in your tenant table for property_id
   tenant.save

   #the shorter way would just be tenant = Tenate.create(params[tenant]) but I want to emphasize the property_id since this attribute is paramount to your property-tenant relationship
end
```

This should effectively create a form for a new tenant and when you create the actual tenant record, you will save the property ID with the new tenant record.

On another note, I would suggest moving this to the Tenants controller per Rails convention and having the form under the new action since you are really creating a new tenant record.